# chartjs tooltip position out of bounds based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, chart.js

I am using chartjs with the [CoreUI Angular dashboard template](https://coreui.io/angular/docs/charts). I have added a horizontal scroll bar for a line chart that contains a lot of data. The horizontal scroll works fine, and the chart displays nicely but the tooltip will display out of bounds based on where the scrollbar is. So, if the scroll bar hasn't been moved, the tooltip is in the correct position by the point that the cursor in near, but the farther you move the scroll bar, the farther the tooltip will be to the right of the point pushing it out of bounds and creating a scroll bar for the entire webpage.

Before scrolling, tooltip is at correct location.
[image: no scroll]

Scrolling to end, hovering over one of the last points, tooltip is all the way to the right, creating additional whitespace that shouldn't be there
[image: end scroll]

Chart HTML

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: auto;">
  <c-chart 
    [data]="timestampChartData"
    [options]="chartOptions.options"
    type="line" 
    height="600"
    width="3000"
 />
</div>
```

Chart options

```
export const chartJsOptions: any = {
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    interaction: {
      intersect: false,
      mode: 'index',
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
    }
  },
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(151, 187, 205, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(151, 187, 205, 1)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(151, 187, 205, 1)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointStyle: 'circle',
    pointRadius: 5,
  }
}
```

Comment: I have not figured out the solution to this specific problem but have decided to use the [chartjs zoom plugin](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/latest/) instead of a scrollbar which works nicely.